# How to config tomcat like this in IDEA?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, intellij-idea

When I use the eclipse + tomcat,  I can set "Use Tomcat installation" as the deployment location.  I want ask whether it's possbile to config it in IDEA.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your Tomcat application server like shown in the screenshot, IDEA will use the Tomcat binaries from "D:\Programme\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\bin" and the Tomcat configuration from "D:\catalina-base-idea\conf".
[image]

[image]

[image]

When you run "yourWebApp", IDEA will create a directory structure in the folder "\system\tomcat". This is the place where your application will be deployed to.

**Update / another way for deploying**

If you're familiar with maven, you can use the tomcat7-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- Tomcat 8 , too -->
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <server>tomcat8-local</server>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <path>/doormanP0</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But what I want is that all the war files directly deploy in the installed tomcat's webapps folder. I don't want the IDEA to deploy to the created \USER\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat folder.

Comment: @superleo: I understand what you mean. As far as I know, the way I showed is the most similar to eclipse in IDEA. It is meant for testing the application. I'll edit my answer to show you a way for deploying your webapp to Tomcat.

Comment: Since my project is a Portal based web application, it cannot run just like a stand-alone context. Anyway, thanks very much. I have resolved it by remote configuration.