# How to create and deploy war in Intellij

Tags: java, macos, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project in my IntelliJ environment. I want to create and deploy war for only one module in apache tomcat. (IntelliJ comes with default installation of tomcat.)

I have worked almost four years with Eclipse and started with IntelliJ like three days back. Just the way we right click on the project in eclipse and say export as war and it directly deploys in my app server, can I do same / similar in IntelliJ?

Any help will be helpful.

Thanks

PS : may be stupid to ask but  would mac / windows make difference?

Comment: This might help you: [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 Help /Developing a Java EE Application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/developing-a-java-ee-application.html). See the sections for: - [Packaging the application into a WAR file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/developing-a-java-ee-application.html?#d121447e467) - [Deploying an artifact onto a running server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/developing-a-java-ee-application.html?origin=old_help#d121447e535)

Comment: there are some differences between "deploying via maven" and "deploying via IntelliJ". You can go both ways comfortably using IntelliJ.

Comment: If you want to go the [maven way, you can find informations here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27317631/1988304). If you want to deploy [via IntelliJ only, look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35601869/1988304) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30297935/1988304)

Comment: RE: Mac/Windows: as you're developing in Java, the OS doesn't really matter and IntelliJ will work the same. The only difference comes if you have to use a terminal/command line at which point the commands might be a little different.

Answer (score 20):

**This absolutely works!**

**First:**

Wow, I was reading and trying the answers provided and I couldn't believe why no one mentions the root of the issue, which is "NOT MENTIONING THE WAY YOU WANT YOUR OUTPUT TO BE", which is `war`, so let's first tell IntelliJ what we want by adding the tag below to your `pom.xml`

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

where to paste? Anywhere inside `<project>` tag.

***Now let's talk about the method***

You can install "Maven Helper" plugin as it will help beginners nicely, but if your IntelliJ has a good handshake with maven, it will automatically or manually refresh your project and add the war capability to your maven settings ( the panel you see at the right hand side of the editor that mentions Maven) there you click on Plugins and you should see now you have `war (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:xxx)` as you click on the + you see many options, war:war and war:exploded are your friends to do what you like

```
      <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

[image]

Use clean to dust off the previous mess, use war:war to create .war file, and for manifest war:exploded will do, if these didn't help for manifest, use the

File | Project Structure and click Artifacts.
Click Add + and  'Web Application:war exploded' then it will pop-up your project and select it and hit OK and then go and do Build > Build Artifact.

Good luck.

Comment: Adding <packaging>war</packaging> is crucial. It works. This must be the accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed, it works. If you get this error "cannot access defaults field of properties", you will have to follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68484632/14103174). It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 17):

IntelliJ has different process to build war:

Goto -> Files -> Project Structure -> Artifacts

In artifacts tab, you will see a small + button on top right corner.
Click it and fill up the right panel data such as name and output directory.

Make sure to create the Manifest file. Keep default location for Manifest file.

After building manifest, click apply->Ok.

Now you can go to Build-> Build Artifact.

Your .war file will be ready in the output folder you specified above.

Comment: this is only for IntelliJ Ultimate, can I create war with IntelliJ Community, thank you.

Comment: Even after clean and rebuild I find that this builds a war that loads into TC but fails with a 404.  Anyone else getting same/solution?

Answer (score 10):

you can use maven build to create war file.
Go to right maven -> Lifecycle -> double click package. You can see your war generated default directory i.e Target

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to realise that you can't build a war file with IntelliJ community edition, at least I could not do it looking at answers from this thread.

My approach was to download and activate "Maven Helper" plugin directly from the IDE ie. File->settings->Plugins.

Then, select your pom.xml in the project viewer and in the "Run" tab, you will be able to choose Run new Maven Goal.
There, simply add the command line "clean install".
Your war file (if you selected `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml file) will be located under the folder "target" in your project main folder.

Answer (score 3):

1. **File | Project Structure** `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S` and click **Artifacts**.
2. Click Add + and create a **Web Application: Archive** For **'Web Application:war exploded'**
3. **Build | Build Artifacts** > **Web Application: war** > Build

You should see the artifact `<project >/out/artifacts/Web Application_war.war`

GL

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/deploying-a-web-app-into-an-app-server-container.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Step-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njpy9.png)

[Step-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi9xM.png) [Step-2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdirQ.png)

[Step-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xALH0.png) [Step-3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIyls.png)

[Step-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvuRB.png) [Step-4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlguf.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOMMR.png)

07/2022

1. **File | Project Structure** `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S` and *click* **Artifacts**.
2. *Click* **Add** + and *select* **'Web Application:war exploded'** *click* **'From modunles..'** and *select* **Modules**
3. *Click* **Add** + and *select* **'Web Application:war Archive'** *click* **'Modules:war exploded'**
4. **Build | Build Artifacts** > **Web Application: war** > **Build**

You should see the .war file in **'out/artifacts/'**. And you can use it to deloy onto the *Glassfish Server*