# Maven error Cannot access defaults field of Properties

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I use the newest version of Java -> 16. When I run mvn clean, I am getting ***Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer*** error. I read that adding maven-war-plugin can be a solution, but it didn't work for me. When I run mvn install, the following error occurs:

> Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
> **Cannot access defaults field of Properties   at**
> org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.(Unknown Source)   while
> locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

How can I solve these problems? Are they caused by the Java version?

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>web-programming</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-demo</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>16</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Optional. Allows the app to be run by simply typing mvn jetty:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.13</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <connectors>
                    <connector
                        implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9090</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your maven version is comparable with your java version or not?

Comment: You are using a ca. 9 year old pluing (maven-war-plugin) and a 13 year old plugin (maven-jetty-plugin) and you should use the most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ furthermore

Comment: I changed the versions of maven-war-plugin and maven-jetty-plugin and the errors disappeared. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sani please post a solution and validate it

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Change the version of the war plugin in your `pom.xml` and add `maven-compiler-plugin` according to your jdk version.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: just adjusting the war-plugin version helped, omitting the compiler-plugin version (no `<version>...` part)

Answer (score 6):

with in your `build` tag paste below code

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <pluginManagement>
   
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
         </plugin>
    
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.2</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.0</version>
         </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>`enter code here`
     <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Add this plugin in `pom.xml` file in between  .
error will vanish

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?